# How can we uncheck ipv6 using powershell in windows

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can we uncheck ipv6 using powershell in windows.

Thanks
Vinith

Comment: @richard does disabled & uncheck means the same?

Comment: Uncheck it from where? What are you talking about? There's no IPv6 in PowerShell.

Comment: @code gray.. what i meant is to uncheck ipv6 in a NIC card using powershell

Comment: ok if idont want to disable them, atleast is there any way that its unchecked!!??

Comment: @VinithMenon "uncheck ipv6 in a NIC card using powershell": so disabling removing IPv6. Untick is that you do to the GUI control, disable is what you do to the functionality controller by that tick box.

Comment: @Vinith: You're contradicting yourself. If you disable it, it will probably be unchecked. If you don't want to disable it, it will probably have to remain checked. *(As I take a wild shot in the dark at interpreting your question.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that disabling IPv6 can cause some troubles. For example, Exchange 2010 [goes haywire](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgoldman/archive/2009/11/03/ip-v6-is-a-must-if-you-are-trying-to-install-exchange-2010.aspx) if IPv6 isn't available.

That being said, this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852) describes which registry keys affect IPv6.

Of course, a [group policy](http://www.expta.com/2009/02/how-to-configure-ipv6-using-group.html) is likely to be better an alternative.

Comment: ok if idont want to disable them, atleast is there any way that its unchecked!!??

Comment: IPv6 does cause issues in an env when you are using IPv6 only, esp in VMware, so turn it off. I am also looking for a discover and disable PS script.